# What would be an example of Neumann boundary conditions on a two dimensional domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition) says that it would involve the derivative with respect to some normal vector being constant, but I don't quite understand this.

- Is the value of the normal vector adjusted across the domain, or does it remain the same?
- Can I say that the standard partial derivative is the derivative with respect to the normal vector if I have a rectangular domain?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the value of the normal vector adjusted across the domain, or does it remain the same?

Consider a domain (nonempty connected open set) $\Omega\subset{\bf R}^n$ with smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$. At each point $x\in\partial \Omega$, we have a normal vector $n(x)$.

[image]

[image]

Consider for instance $\Omega$ being a closed unit ball in ${\bf R}^n$ (in the case when $n=2$, you have a closed unit disk). One has
$$
n(x)=x.
$$

A particular [Neumann boundary condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition) looks like
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(x)=f(x),\quad x\in\partial \Omega
$$
which is understood as
$$
\nabla u(x)\cdot n(x)=f(x),\quad x\in\partial\Omega.
$$

---

> Can I say that the standard partial derivative is the derivative with respect to the normal vector if I have a rectangular domain?

I would not say that. Note that the directional derivative in the direction of a normal vector only makes sense on the boundary of a domain. But you might have [something like this](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M257_316_2012_Lecture_25.pdf):

[image]